# Hodge theory beyond Riemannian and Kahler manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, hodge-theory

Recently I read about graph-theoretic Hodge theory, which has uses in graph theory, topological data analysis, and more generally machine learning. I knew only the basics of Riemannian Hodge theory, and this baffled me completely. My question is then: how far can we go with Hodge theory?

Examples I know:

- $p$-adic Hodge theory and noncommutative Hodge theory, which are both quite famous;
- the Hodge theory of metric spaces (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.0284.pdf) by Bartholdi et al.);
- the "discrete" Hodge theory of simplicial complexes and graphs (or CW complexes).

The question is, how far could we possibly go? Say, can we generalize Hodge-like theories to any abelian sheaf on a site? What would be the main difficulties in doing so?

Comment: People call stuff Hodge theory if it reminds them of stuff that people already call Hodge theory. E.g. Laplacians might show up, or perhaps some structure appears that reminds them of the Hodge decomposition. So the question might not be all that well posed.

Comment: @DonuArapura Thank you Donu. IMO the most important characteristic is probably the existence of Hodge-like decompositions. By the way, I really like your book!

Answer (score 5):

There is a [Hodge theory for matroids](https://mattbaker.blog/2015/12/14/hodge-theory-in-combinatorics/), which uses the Hodge-Riemann bilinear relations from algebraic geometry to prove statements about matroids realizable over $\mathbb C$, and generalize them to all matroids.